# Move X-Axis label downwards, but not X-Axis Ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I'm using Matplotlib to plot a histogram.
Using tips from my previous question: [Matplotlib - label each bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352740/matplotlib-label-each-bin),
I've more or less got the kinks worked out.

There's one final issue - previously - the x-axis label ("Time (in milliseconds)") was being rendered underneath the x-axis tickmarks (0.00, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12 etc.)

[image: No padding - Axis label underneath figures]

Using the advice from Joe Kingston (see question above), I tried using:

```py
ax.tick_params(axis='x', pad=30)
```

However, this moves both the x-axis tickmarks (0.00, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12 etc.), as well as the x-axis label ("Time (in milliseconds)"):

[image: 30 Padding - Both Axis Label and Tick Marks have Moved]

Is there any way to move only the x-axis label to underneath the three rows of figures?

*NB: You may need to open the PNGs below directly - Right Click on the image, then View Image (in FF), or Open image in new tab (Chrome). The image resize done by SO has rendered them nigh unreadable*

Answer (score 269, accepted):

use labelpad parameter:

```
pl.xlabel("...", labelpad=20)
```

or set it after:

```
ax.xaxis.labelpad = 20
```

Comment: if I use this and save the figure, the figure is cropped and I don't see the label anymore

Answer (score 14):

If the variable ax.xaxis._autolabelpos = True, matplotlib sets the label position in function _update_label_position in axis.py according to (some excerpts):

```
    bboxes, bboxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw, renderer)
    bbox = mtransforms.Bbox.union(bboxes)
    bottom = bbox.y0
    x, y = self.label.get_position()
    self.label.set_position((x, bottom - self.labelpad * self.figure.dpi / 72.0))
```

You can set the label position independently of the ticks by using:

```
    ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(x0, y0)
```

that sets _autolabelpos to False or as mentioned above by changing the labelpad parameter.

Comment: For posterity, matplotlib now has [`.set_label_coords`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_coords.html) which gives a similar level of control

Answer (score 1):

Instead of padding manually, try assigning vertical alignment (`va=`):

```py
ax.set_xlabel("x label", va='top');
```

If you modify the label padding manually as in @HYRY's answer, sometimes when you save the figure the label is cropped off. To include the label, set `bbox_inches='tight'` when you call `savefig()`. For example:

```py
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.xlabel("x label", labelpad=30);
plt.savefig('img.png', bbox_inches='tight');
```

With the OOP API, the same would be:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.set_xlabel("x label", labelpad=30);
fig.savefig('img.png', bbox_inches='tight');
```