# Python Matplotlib figure title overlaps axes label when using twiny

Tags: python, matplotlib, title, figure

I am trying to plot two separate quantities on the same graph using twiny as follows:

```
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(T, r, 'b-', T, R, 'r-', T, r_geo, 'g-')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.annotate('Approx. sea level', xy=(Planet.T_day*1.3,(Planet.R)/1000), xytext=(Planet.T_day*1.3, Planet.R/1000))
ax.annotate('Geostat. orbit', xy=(Planet.T_day*1.3, r_geo[0]), xytext=(Planet.T_day*1.3, r_geo[0]))
ax.set_xlabel('Rotational period (hrs)')
ax.set_ylabel('Orbital radius (km), logarithmic')
ax.set_title('Orbital charts for ' + Planet.N, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='top')


ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.plot(v,r,'k-')
ax2.set_xlabel('Linear speed (ms-1)')

show()
```

and the data is presented fine, but I am having the problem that the figure title is overlapping with the axes labels on the secondary x axis so that it's barely legible (I wanted to post a picture example here, but I don't have a high enough rep yet).

I'd like to know if there's a straightforward way to just shift the title directly up a few tens of pixels, so that the chart looks prettier.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it is a new feature in later versions of matplotlib, but at least for 1.3.1, this is simply:

```
plt.title(figure_title, y=1.08)
```

This also works for `plt.suptitle()`, but not (yet) for `plt.xlabel()`, etc.

Comment: For labels you can set the argument `labelpad`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6406750/692634).

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not a new feature. `title` has taken `x` and `y` arguments for a very long time (as long as I can remember, at any rate).

Comment: plt.set_title('title string', y = 1.08) works for me.

Comment: It would be more helpful if someone explained what units 1.08 is and what are the defaults. My understanding is that default is 1

Comment: @konpsych I agree, the default is actually 0 according to the [Text object docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) but I'm not sure what units are.

Comment: @JohnCummings It seems that the default value is y=1 and the units is "axes fraction", i.e., y=0.5 means the title is in the middle of the axes, and y=0 means the title is just above the bottom of the axes.

Comment: @herrlich10 thank you for the information on the units - where did you find that detail? Also, the only default I see for y is `y=0` in the Text object docs that I linked to. Where did you find `y=1` as the default value?

Comment: @JohnCummings It's in the source code of [`_AxesBase`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py) class. Search for "self.title" in the file.

Comment: This works when iterating through axes too.

Answer (score 37):

Forget using `plt.title` and place the text directly with `plt.text`. An over-exaggerated example is given below:

```
import pylab as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,10))

figure_title = "Normal title"
ax1  = plt.subplot(1,2,1)

plt.title(figure_title, fontsize = 20)
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])

figure_title = "Raised title"
ax2  = plt.subplot(1,2,2)

plt.text(0.5, 1.08, figure_title,
         horizontalalignment='center',
         fontsize=20,
         transform = ax2.transAxes)
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @user815423426 yes, `tight_layout` still doesn't seem to play nicely with non-standard placements. Perhaps you could make a bug report?

Comment: I found a work around when using tight_layout, at least when you save your plot using [figure.savefig()](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig). If
`title = plt.title(...)` then you can specify to frame the plot tightly around the title using the option  `bbox_extra_artists` :
`figure.savefig(filename, bbox_extra_artists=(title), bbox_inches='tight')`

Answer (score 25):

I was having an issue with the x-label overlapping a subplot title; this worked for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax[0].scatter(...)
ax[1].scatter(...)
plt.tight_layout()
.
.
.
plt.show()
```

## before

[image]

## after

[image]

reference:

- https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html

Comment: I also use `tight_layout()` but unfortunately if title has `backgroundcolor` set, there is still overlap

Answer (score 12):

```
ax.set_title('My Title\n', fontsize="15", color="red")
plt.imshow(myfile, origin="upper")
```

If you put `'\n'` right after your title string, the plot is drawn just below the title. That might be a fast solution too.

Answer (score 11):

You can use pad for this case:

```
ax.set_title("whatever", pad=20)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.show()`. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution if you don't want to get into the `x`, `y` position of your title.

Following worked for me.

```
plt.title('Capital Expenditure\n') # Add a next line after your title
```

kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `plt.tight_layout()` before the `plt.show()` works for me well.

you can even make it better and visible by adding a padding

```
ax.set_title("title", pad=15)
```