# Python customised title and legend in figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to show a legend near the top of my figure (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)) and a title above that (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750355/python-matplotlib-figure-title-overlaps-axes-label-when-using-twiny))

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1,24,1)
y = np.array([400,650,1020,1300,1600,1950,2200,2550,2850,3150,3400,3550,3800,3950,4050,4150,4210,4250,4300,4320,4310,4300,4200])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax.plot(x,y,'o', label='data set 1')
plt.text(0.5, 1.4, 'Data set A-1', 
        horizontalalignment='center', 
        fontsize=16,
        transform = ax.transAxes)
ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylim(ymax=5000)

ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.25),
          ncol=3, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

fig.savefig('test.pdf')
```

However, when I save this graph, both the title and legend are missing. Only the axes and datapoints are saved in the pdf.

Comment: which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.7, Spyder 2.3.0 (but it's got nothing to do with Spyder)

Comment: They are *too* far above and just not in the figure's view. Try resizing the figure to be small and they start to show up...

Comment: If you change the 1.4 to 1.1 and the 1.25 to 1.05 you will see them.

Comment: @Agean The title in test.pdf is (horizontally) chopped in half. But if 1.4->1.05 and 1.25->1.05 and `fontsize=14`, then it's OK...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are moving them out of the visible area.  If you use `set_title` mpl will take care it's placement for you.  Same with the bounding box on the legend:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1,24,1)
y = np.array([400,650,1020,1300,1600,1950,2200,2550,2850,3150,3400,3550,3800,3950,4050,4150,4210,4250,4300,4320,4310,4300,4200])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax.plot(x,y,'o', label='data set 1')
ax.set_title('Data set A-1')

ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylim(ymax=5000)

ax.legend(loc='upper center', 
          ncol=3, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You probably also want to pass `num_points=1` as a kwarg to `legend`.

Answer (score 1):

Do You want the legend be on axes also?

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1,24,1)
y = np.array([400,650,1020,1300,1600,1950,2200,2550,
              2850,3150,3400,3550,3800,3950,4050,4150,
              4210,4250,4300,4320,4310,4300,4200])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax.plot(x,y,'o', label='data set 1')

ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylim(ymax=5000)


ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05),
          ncol=3, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
title = ax.set_title('Data set A-1')

fig.tight_layout()

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
title.set_y(1.07)

fig.savefig("13.png")
```