# How do I add spacing below the title on a basemap figure?

Tags: python, title, patch, matplotlib-basemap

I want to add a spacing between the figure and the title. Right now, the title is overlapping with the meridions as in the figure below and I would like avoid that. Can someone tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance!

[image: Basemap Plot]

Comment: Are you using `plot.title()` or `plot.suptitle()`?

Comment: I'm using plot.title().

Comment: You essentially have a Matplotlib figure. Does the first answer here work?
`plot.title('Variance', y=1.08)`

[Python Matplotlib figure title overlaps axes label...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750355/python-matplotlib-figure-title-overlaps-axes-label-when-using-twiny)

Comment: If you try `plot.suptitle()` you will find that it places the title a bit higher than `plot.title()` does. Try that to see if it fixes it.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. plot.title('Variance', y=1.08) works great! The plot.suptitle() function works fine when there is only one plot but does not work well when I want to have individual titles over each subplot.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `suptitle()` function and resize your figure.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
# create Basemap instance.
m = Basemap(projection='lcc',lat_0=-30,lon_0=-50,
            llcrnrlat=-30,urcrnrlat=10,
            llcrnrlon=-80,urcrnrlon=-20,
            resolution='c')
# draw coastlines, state and country boundaries, edge of map.
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()

# draw parallels.
parallels = np.arange(-90.,90,10.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)
# draw meridians
meridians = np.arange(180.,360.,10.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,1,1],fontsize=10)

# add title
plt.title('PROBLEM!!')


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
# create Basemap instance.
m = Basemap(projection='lcc',lat_0=-30,lon_0=-50,
            llcrnrlat=-30,urcrnrlat=10,
            llcrnrlon=-80,urcrnrlon=-20,
            resolution='c')
# draw coastlines, state and country boundaries, edge of map.
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()

# draw parallels.
parallels = np.arange(-90.,90,10.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)
# draw meridians
meridians = np.arange(180.,360.,10.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,1,1],fontsize=10)

# add title
plt.suptitle('NO PROBLEM!!')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this what do you want?