# place top x-axis label on the inside of the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph with two x axis label, top and bottom. The top label is running into the title of the graph. Is there anyway to put labels on the inside of the graph? I don't see it in the documentation.

The alternative is to use a raised title, but I can't do that because my graphs are stacked. The raised title from graph below will get mixed up with the graph above it:

[Python Matplotlib figure title overlaps axes label when using twiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750355/python-matplotlib-figure-title-overlaps-axes-label-when-using-twiny)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can move the location of axis labels using [`set_label_coords`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_coords).

The coords you give it are `x` and `y`, and by default the transform is the axes coordinate system: so `(0,0)` is `(left,bottom)`, `(0.5, 0.5)` is in the middle, etc.

So, an `x coord` of `0.5` centres the text, and a `y coord` of `0.95` brings the label inside the plot, below the top axis.

Here's a quick example code to show how to do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2=ax1.twiny()

ax1.set_xlabel('xlabel 1')
ax2.set_xlabel('xlabel 2')

ax2.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5,0.95)

ax1.set_title('my title')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: very helpful, based on your answer, i tried the following and it worked. `ax2.set_xticklabels(xlabels, fontsize=11,y=0.85)`