# Changing x axis position from top to bottom on plt.Matshow

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've searched high and low, but I can't seem to move the x axis from top to bottom using Matshow, I'm aware that imshow has the origin code to change the x axis position from top to bottom, but the question that I've got insists that I use Matshow, therefore is there a way to switch the a axis position?

```
t = [[(x+y+1)%2 for x in range(7)] for y in range (7)]
plt.matshow(t, interpolation="none")
plt.title('ArrayD')`
```

Answer (score 10):

Either call `tick_bottom()`:

```
plt.matshow(t, interpolation="none")
plt.gca().xaxis.tick_bottom()
```

or use `imshow` instead of `matshow`:

```
plt.imshow(t, interpolation="none")
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = [[(x+y+1)%2 for x in range(7)] for y in range (7)]
plt.matshow(t, interpolation="none")
plt.title('ArrayD', y=1.01)
plt.gca().xaxis.tick_bottom()
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Now there's a small margin between the title and the plot , is it possible to close the gap?

Comment: You could use `plt.title('ArrayD', y=1.01)` to tighten the gap. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23338363/190597.