# Pyplot: leaving space for a bigger title

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
sns.boxplot(data=df, width=0.5)
plt.title(f'Distribution of scores for initial and resubmission\
           \nonly among students who resubmitted at all.\
           \n(n = {df.shape[0]})')
```

I want to use a bigger font, and leave more space in the top white margin so that the title doesn't get crammed in. Surprisingly, I am totally unable to find the option despite some serious googling!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Matplotlib figure title overlaps axes label when using twiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750355/python-matplotlib-figure-title-overlaps-axes-label-when-using-twiny)

Answer (score 8):

The basic problem you have is that the multi-line title is too tall, and is rendered "off the page".

A few options for you:

- the least effort solution is probably to use [`tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html). `plt.tight_layout()` manipulates the subplot locations and spacing so that labels, ticks and titles fit more nicely.
- if this isn't enough, also look at [`plt.subplots_adjust()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=subplots_adjust#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) which gives you control over how much whitespace is used around one or more subfigures; you can modify just one aspect at at time, and all the other settings are left alone.  In your case, you could use `plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)`.
- If you are generating a final figure for publication or similar, you might be aiming to tweak a lot to perfect it.  In this case, you can precisely control the (sub)plot locations, using `add_axes` (see this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/17479417).

Here is an example, with a 6-line title for emphasis. The left panel shows the default - with half the title clipped off.  The right panel has all measurements the same except the top; the middle has automatically removed whitespace on all sides.

[image: improved title handling]

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = 55 + 5* np.random.randn(1000,)    # some data
vlongtitle = "\n".join(["long title"]*6) # a 6-line title

# using tight_layout, all the margins are reduced
plt.figure()
sns.boxplot(data, width=0.5)
plt.title(vlongtitle)
plt.tight_layout()

# 2nd option, just edit one aspect.
plt.figure()
sns.boxplot(data, width=0.5)
plt.title(vlongtitle)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.72)
```