# PyPlot - Additional padding for xticklabels if keywords are not enough

Tags: python, matplotlib, padding

I have a plot where I set my ticks and labels manually, because pyplot did not do the job to my full satisfaction. I align the labels using the following code:

```
for tick in self.axes.xaxis.get_minorticklabels():
    tick.set_horizontalalignment('right')
    tick.set_rotation(40)
```

This is basically fine, but I'd like the labels to move a little bit further to the left (`center` is too far). I only found padding for the axis label in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406368/matplotlib-move-x-axis-label-downwards-but-not-x-axis-ticks#6406750), but not for the tick labels. Is there something similar like `labelpad=X` to move the tick labels in horizontal direction?

Comment: Are you asking for horizontal padding or vertical padding here?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying that... I'm looking for horizontal padding to move only the label itself, not the tick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Axes.set_tick_params()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) function to adjust the padding between the axe and the tick labels (minor, major, or both)

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='minor', pad=25)
```

Comment: A good start, but this moves the labels up or down, not left or right.