# How do I add words to the axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a colormap in matplotlib. I am unsure of how to edit the axis values so that they display words rather than numbers. I am plotting on the colormap the change in states of species in a network with the inclusion of an inhibitor, so I want the inhibitor name to be on the y-axis and then the names of the observed species on the x-axis. For instance, if I introduce inhibitor z, and I observe the states of the species A,B,C and D, then I would want z on the y-axis and A, B, C, and D on the x-axis. I want no tick-marks or anything just the words.

Comment: you have to copy/paste some of your relevant codes here, it's unclear to me whether you want ticklabels or axes labels in strings.

Comment: Seems like a bit of searching would have turned up [how to set custom ticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559242/matplotlib-strings-as-labels-on-x-axis), where the defined `t11` is where you would write out A, B, C, and D.  Read [here](http://www.shocksolution.com/2011/08/removing-an-axis-or-both-axes-from-a-matplotlib-plot/) on how to turn off the tick-marks.