# Matplotlib: how to plot a line with categorical data on the x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, categorical-data

I am trying to plot **a few lines** (not a bar plot, as in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559242/matplotlib-strings-as-labels-on-x-axis)). My y values are `float`, whereas x values are `categorical data`. How to do this in `matplotlib`?

My values:

```
data1=[5.65,7.61,8.17,7.60,9.54]
data2=[7.61,16.17,16.18,19.54,19.81] 
data3=[29.55,30.24,31.51,36.40,35.47]
```

My categories:

```
x_axis=['A','B','C','D','E']
```

The code I am using, which does not give me what I want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure() #Creates a new figure
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111) #Plot with: 1 row, 1 column, first subplot.
line1 = ax1.plot(str(x_axis), data1,'ko-',label='line1') #Plotting data1
line2 = ax1.plot(str(x_axis), data2,'ro-',label='line2') #Plotting data2
line3 = ax1.plot(str(x_axis), data3,'mo-',label='line3') #Plotting data3
plt.xticks(range(len(data3)), x_axis, size='small')
ax1.set_ylim(0,51)
ax1.set_ylabel('y values',fontsize=12)
#Assigning labels
lines = line1+line2+line3
labels = [l.get_label() for l in lines]
ax1.legend(lines,labels,loc='upper center', prop={'size':10}, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.13), fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)
ax1.set_xlabel('Categories',fontsize=14)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
title_string=('Plotting categories vs y values in matplotlib')
plt.suptitle(title_string, y=1.0, fontsize=17)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.92,bottom=0.2)
plt.show() 
plt.savefig('myplot.jpg',bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib strings as labels on x axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559242/matplotlib-strings-as-labels-on-x-axis)

Comment: That was referring to a bar plot. This is a line plot.

Comment: You want the x_axis to be "A", "B"... instead of 1,2..., right ? You can do this with `xticks`. If you want something more complex, an image of the result would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks incorrect with regards to some syntax:

```
line1 = ax1.plot(data1,'ko-',label='line1') #no need for str(x_axis)
line2 = ax1.plot(data2,'ro-',label='line2') 
line3 = ax1.plot(data3,'mo-',label='line3')
```

and

```
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=True) #not ax2
```

When I fixed these the plotting worked fine, your line

```
plt.xticks(range(len(data3)), x_axis, size='small')
```

is a correct way to assign a list to the x axis.

Answer (score 8):

Matplotlib version **2.1.0** allows [plotting categorical variables directly](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html), just calling `plt.plot(x,y)` as usual, without the need to use `range` or `get_xticklabels()`.

```
line1 = plt.plot(x_axis, data1,'ko-',label='line1')
line2 = plt.plot(x_axis, data2,'ro-',label='line2') 
line3 = plt.plot(x_axis, data3,'mo-',label='line3')
```

---

[image]