# Setting axis values in numpy/matplotlib.plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am in the process of learning numpy. I wish to plot a graph of Planck's law for different temperatures and so have two `np.array`s, `T` and `l` for temperature and wavelength respectively.

```
import scipy.constants as sc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lhinm = 10000                         # Highest wavelength in nm
T = np.linspace(200, 1000, 10)        # Temperature in K
l = np.linspace(0, lhinm*1E-9, 101)   # Wavelength in m
labels = np.linspace(0, lhinm, 6)     # Axis labels giving l in nm

B = (2*sc.h*sc.c**2/l[:, np.newaxis]**5)/(np.exp((sc.h*sc.c)/(T*l[:, np.newaxis]*sc.Boltzmann))-1)

for ticks in [True, False]:
    plt.plot(B)
    plt.xlabel("Wavelength (nm)")
    if ticks:
        plt.xticks(l, labels)
        plt.title("With xticks()")
        plt.savefig("withticks.png")
    else:
        plt.title("Without xticks()")
        plt.savefig("withoutticks.png")
    plt.show()
```

I would like to label the x-axis with the wavelength in nm. If I don't call `plt.xitcks()` the labels on the x-axis would appear to be the index in to the array B (which holds the caculated values).

[image: Without ticks]

I've seen answer [7559542](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559242/matplotlib-strings-as-labels-on-x-axis), but when I call `plt.xticks()` all the values are scrunched up on the left of the axis, rather than being evenly spread along it.

[image: With ticks]

So what's the best way to define my own set of values (in this case a subset of the values in `l`) and place them on the axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not giving your wavelength values to `plt.plot()`, so Matplotlib puts the index into the array on the horizontal axis as a default. Quick solution:

```
plt.plot(l, B)
```

Without explicitly setting tick labels, that gives you this:

[image: plot with proper values on x axis]

Of course, the values on the horizontal axis in this plot are actually in meters, not nanometers (despite the labeling), because the values you passed as the first argument to `plot()` (namely the array `l`) are in meters. That's where `xticks()` comes in. The two-argument version [`xticks(locations, labels)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) places the labels at the corresponding locations on the x axis. For example, `xticks([1], 'one')` would put a label "one" at the location x=1, if that location is in the plot.

However, it doesn't change the range displayed on the axis. In your original example, your call to `xticks()` placed a bunch of labels at coordinates like 10<sup>-9</sup>, but it didn't change the axis range, which was still 0 to 100. No wonder all the labels were squished over to the left.

What you need to do is call `xticks()` with the points at which you want to place the labels, and the desired text of the labels. The way you were doing it, `xticks(l, labels)`, would work except that `l` has length 101 and `labels` only has length 6, so it only uses the first 6 elements of `l`. To fix that, you can do something like

```
plt.xticks(labels * 1e-9, labels)
```

where the multiplication by `1e-9` converts from nanometers (what you want displayed) to meters (which are the coordinates Matplotlib actually uses in the plot).

[image: fixed plot with proper labels]

Answer (score 3):

You can supply the `x` values to `plt.plot`, and let matplotlib take care of setting the tick labels.

In your case, you could plot `plt.plot(l, B)`, but then you still have the ticks in m, not nm.

You could therefore convert your `l` array to nm before plotting (or during plotting). Here's a working example:

```
import scipy.constants as sc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lhinm = 10000                         # Highest wavelength in nm
T = np.linspace(200, 1000, 10)        # Temperature in K
l = np.linspace(0, lhinm*1E-9, 101)   # Wavelength in m
l_nm = l*1e9                          # Wavelength in nm
labels = np.linspace(0, lhinm, 6)     # Axis labels giving l in nm

B = (2*sc.h*sc.c**2/l[:, np.newaxis]**5)/(np.exp((sc.h*sc.c)/(T*l[:, np.newaxis]*sc.Boltzmann))-1)

plt.plot(l_nm, B)
# Alternativly:
# plt.plot(l*1e9, B)
plt.xlabel("Wavelength (nm)")
plt.title("With xticks()")
plt.savefig("withticks.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use same size lists at the `xtick`. Try setting the axis values separately from the plot value as below.

```
import scipy.constants as sc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lhinm = 10000                         # Highest wavelength in nm
T = np.linspace(200, 1000, 10)        # Temperature in K
l = np.linspace(0, lhinm*1E-9, 101)   # Wavelength in m
ll = np.linspace(0, lhinm*1E-9, 6)    # Axis values
labels = np.linspace(0, lhinm, 6)     # Axis labels giving l in nm

B = (2*sc.h*sc.c**2/l[:, np.newaxis]**5)/(np.exp((sc.h*sc.c)/(T*l[:, np.newaxis]*sc.Boltzmann))-1)

for ticks in [True, False]:
    plt.plot(B)
    plt.xlabel("Wavelength (nm)")
    if ticks:
        plt.xticks(ll, labels)
        plt.title("With xticks()")
        plt.savefig("withticks.png")
    else:
        plt.title("Without xticks()")
        plt.savefig("withoutticks.png")
    plt.show()
```