# Tweaking Numbers of X-Label in MatPlotLib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-analysis

I'm trying to use matplotlib to create a scatter plot of property price by zip code. The problem I am having is that it won't show the zip code on the bottom. It's giving it in annotated scientific notation, like so:

[scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI9Gi.png)

How do I format those labels so that I get the specific zip code? EG, 77062, 77053.

This is a different plot type than the one mentioned below. When I follow the instructions on that one I get this return for a plot: 
[Incorrect Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN5rW.png)

This is not what I am looking for, there will be multiple zipcodes when this is finished. The prices would overlap, it would be ugly. This is why I wanted to do a scatter plot.

Comment: Try the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559242/matplotlib-strings-as-labels-on-x-axis

Comment: I checked it out and edited the original comments. For some reason, I can't get it to work.

Comment: Where is the difference between the solution in the duplicate and this, except that you need to call `scatter` instead of `bar`.