# How do I change the x-axis to display 'State' on matplotlib inline

Tags: python, jupyter

How do I get the state name to show in x-axis instead of the numbers and how can I display the chart with different colors. margin of victory by state:

[image: margin of victory by state]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib strings as labels on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559242/matplotlib-strings-as-labels-on-x-axis)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xticks` function to change the x-axis labels. In your case, this would look something like this:

```
plt.xticks(locs=list(range(37)), labels=[list of state names goes here])
```

Documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html).

Comment: Thank Hoffee, It works now with this line

plt.xticks(range(37), [list of state names goes here])

plt.show()