# How plot a histogram in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matplotlib - label each bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352740/matplotlib-label-each-bin)

I can't fully understand how it works... also, there are `hist` and `bar` - `bar` is more clear for me, but... how can I plot `histogram`, where one values are strings?
input data like is:

```
cars 1000
bikes 1500
buses 100
```

Also, I have to use it into web application, so I need to save the image as bytes or something like that

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352740/matplotlib-label-each-bin

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373884/displaying-fixed-width-bars-for-all-datasets-in-matplotlib