# Share x axis between matplotlib and seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, axis, axis-labels

I have data in pandas `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(786)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(0, 1, 0.05),
                   'b':np.random.rand(20) - .5})

print (df)
       a         b
0   0.00  0.256682
1   0.05 -0.192555
2   0.10  0.393919
3   0.15 -0.113310
4   0.20  0.373855
5   0.25 -0.423764
6   0.30 -0.123428
7   0.35 -0.173446
8   0.40  0.440818
9   0.45 -0.016878
10  0.50  0.055467
11  0.55 -0.165294
12  0.60 -0.216684
13  0.65  0.011099
14  0.70  0.059425
15  0.75  0.145865
16  0.80 -0.019171
17  0.85  0.116984
18  0.90 -0.051583
19  0.95 -0.096527
```

I would like plot `barplot` and add vertical line:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.barplot(x = 'a', y = 'b', data = df)
plt.vlines(x = 0.45, ymin = 0, ymax = 0.6, color = 'red', linewidth=5)
```

There are problems with ticklabels, because overlaping and also line should be in point `0.45` instaed near `0` for `x axis`.

[image: polt]

I try many solutions from [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810319), 
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11039268),
[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14374131),
[link4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33891421/2901002) but still problem set correctly axis for both plots.

What is problem? Is possible share x axis between plots?

Expected output - correctly aligned vertical line and also not overlaping ticks in x axis:

[image: pic]

Comment: working on it! do i understand correctly that you want to share x axis between a plot and a vertical line?

Comment: @Cut7er - Yes, because need correct align vertical line.

Comment: then i guess my answer is not helpful since it plots two seperate subplots. but if you could put your line somehow in the figure/subplot construct, it should be possible to just share an axis by "sharex = ax1"

Comment: @Cut7er - I try it, but cannot create working solution :(

Comment: have you tried `ax.twiny()`? what is the desired output?

Comment: @Yuca - Please check edited question with expected output.

Comment: no overlapping can be achieved with rotating labels, do you agree?

Comment: @Yuca - hmmm, I try `plt.figure(figsize=(28,10))` and problem seems with `floats` - e.g `0.15` is changed to `0.1500000000002`. So not sure.

Comment: if that is the case ax.set_xticklabels(np.round()) should fix it

Comment: @Yuca - Be free create answer ;) But hardest problem seems with vertical line :(

Comment: since I consider you one of the python masters I didn't want to answer since I feel underqualified, so I gave pointers, I'll give you an answer in an hour, I'm in the middle of something :)

Comment: I played around with the vertical line and `plt.vlines(x = 0.45*20, ...)` seems to work. But that is very strange! Might be a bug between seaborn and matplotlib interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The x-axis in the barplot is categorical, so it doesn't have the values of your `df.a` as a real scale, but only as tick labels. You could change e.g. `df.a[19] = 2` and nothing will change except the label of the last bar tick.

So categorical axis means the coordinates are 0 for the first bar, 1 for the second and so on ... 19 for the last.

My approach then would be to set the vertical line at xpos * 19/.95:

```
plt.vlines(x = .45*19/.95, ymin = 0, ymax = 0.6, color = 'red', linewidth=5)
```

[image]

For the general case you could add a lambda function to calculate the conversion:

```
f = lambda x: (x-df.a.values[0]) * (df.a.size-1) / (df.a.values[-1] - df.a.values[0])
plt.vlines(x = f(.45), ymin = 0, ymax = 0.6, color = 'red', linewidth=5)
```

However, as `df.a.values` is only printed as tick labels, it should go linearly from start to end.

Regarding the problem with x-axis labeling: I just can tell that it doesn't appear at my system, the code for the plot abovevis identical to yours, except the vertical line. Perhaps it was introduced while doing one attempt of vlines after another.

Comment: Can you add picture of plot to answer?

Comment: Consider also adding full graphing code to show how x-axis was resolved.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's obvious by the plot: the graphing code is the identical copy of the one posted in the question - except the last line which plots the vertical line. This one is replaced by the described version. In the general case additionally by the lambda definition.

Comment: You are completely right - I should have adressed the x-axis issue explicitely, as it was part of the question. I'll edit...

Answer (score 1):

Using `ax.twiny` and rounding inputs:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
np.random.seed(786)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.round(np.arange(0, 1, 0.05),2),
                   'b':np.round(np.random.rand(20),2) - .5})


plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'a', y = 'b', data = df)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.vlines(x = 0.45, ymin = 0, ymax = 0.6, color = 'red', linewidth=2)
#ax2.set_visible(False) # this hides the ticks on the top of the plot
```

[image]

Comment: does this answer your question? Hopefully it does! Sorry for being so late

Answer (score 0):

create a figure with two subplots, then you can share x- and y axis between both subplots.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax2 = plt.subplot(212, sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)
```