# Converting an array of numbers into histogram bins

Tags: visualization

I'm using a java program to split an array among histogram bins. Now, I want to manually label the histogram bins. So - I want to convert some thing like the sequence: {-0.9,-0.8,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,4} into the following image -

[image]

Is there a way to do this using any software? I'm on Windows and some thing based on R, python, java or matlab would be awesome. I currently do it manually using mspaint.

Comment: Surely if you label your x axis correctly, and make sure the bars are in the right place (i.e. thinner bars for narrower bins), you won't need such an image? Also, use a graphing package, this is crazy by hand. Histograms in R: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/density.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest approach is (Python):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = [-0.9,-0.8,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,4]
hist(d)

plt.show()
```

As for putting special labels on the histogram, that's covered in the question: [Matplotlib - label each bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352740/matplotlib-label-each-bin).

I'm guessing you want to keep it simple, so you can do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
d = [-0.9,-0.8,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,4]
counts, bins, patches = ax.hist(d)
ax.set_xticks(bins)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To arrange data in bins then display them with equal width bars you can use `matplotlib` in Python

The previous Python answer doesn't bin the values, set them at equal distance nor handle (-infinity, 0.9) bin

The code here hopefully does:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# data and bins
d = [-0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -
     0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 4]
bin_boundaries = [-0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.5, -0.4,
                  -0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 4]
# Account for (-inf, min(d)) bin
added_inf = False
min_d = min(d)
if min_d < bin_boundaries[0]:
    bin_boundaries.insert(0, min_d)
    added_inf = True

# Bin data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
counts, bins, _ = ax.hist(d, bins=bin_boundaries)
plt.close()

# Generate tick labels and handle (-inf, min(d)) bin
bins_str = [f"{bins[i]} to {bins[i+1]}" for i in range(len(bins) - 1)]
if added_inf:
    bins_str[0] = f"-inf to {bins[1]}"
else:
    bins = np.insert(bins, 0, [bins[0] - 1])
    counts = np.insert(counts, 0, [0])
    bins_str.insert(0, f"-inf to {bins[1]}")
    

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Ajdust size of plot
fig.set_dpi(150)
# Draw graph with bins_str as labels
ax.bar(bins_str, counts, width=1.0)
# Make labels vertical
plt.xticks(rotation=90, ha='center')

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

On the java side, an useful (and not too big) library could be GRAL http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/

An histogram example is here:
http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/browser/gral-examples/src/main/java/de/erichseifert/gral/examples/barplot/HistogramPlot.java

And specifically about axis rotation:
http://www.erichseifert.de/dev/gral/0.10/apidocs/de/erichseifert/gral/plots/axes/AxisRenderer.html#setLabelRotation%28double%29