# Python Histogram Bar Labels Bin Count

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, histogram, bin

I have a histogram that I am plotting from a single array.

```
SLT=[ 10.6,  10.5,  10.3,   5.3,   5.3,   5. ,   5. ,   9.3,   3. ,
     8.5,   1.1,   6.4,  23.2,   4.4,  21.2,   2.4,   2.3,   2.3,
     2.2,   2.2,   2.1,   2. ,   2. ,   1.9,  13.9,  13.8,  13.8,
    13.7,  13.7,  13.6,  13.6,  13.6,  13.6,  18.8,  11.5,  11.5,
    11.4,  11.4,  11.4,  11.3,  11.2,  11.1,  11. ,  10.9,  10.7,
    10.5,  10.4,  10.4,  10.3,  10.2,  10.1,  22.1,  22. ,  22. ,
    22. ,  21.9,  21.9,  21.8,  21.8,  21.7,  21.7,  21.6,  17. ,
    17. ,  16.9,  17. ,  21.1,  16.1,  16.1,  16.1,  16.1,  16. ,
    15.8,  20.6,  14.2,  19.8,  12.2,  17.5,  12.9,  18.6,  12.6,
    18.4,  13.7,  13.7,  13.6]
```

I plot a histogram using the following:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
numBins=24
ax.hist(SLT,numBins,color='k',alpha=0.8)
remove_border(left=False,bottom=True)
plt.xlabel('Saturn Local Time')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Cassini Titan Flybys between 2004 - 2014, Distribution of SLT Frequency')
plt.ylim([0,13])
plt.xlim([1,24])
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(b=True,which='major',color='k',alpha=0.2,linestyle='dotted')
plt.grid(b=False,which='minor',color='k',alpha=0.2,linestyle='dotted')
plt.show()
```

This yields: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVdsn.jpg

How can I put a label at the top of each bin which shows the count of that bin? Is there a built in function/workaround or would i need to manually work it out and plot as a textbook for instance?

Many thanks!

---

Answer involved both suggestions in comments:

Overall code:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
numBins=24
counts,bins,patches=ax.hist(SLT,numBins,color='k',alpha=0.8)
remove_border(left=False,bottom=True)
plt.xlabel('Saturn Local Time')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Cassini Titan Flybys between 2004 - 2014, Distribution of SLT Frequency')
plt.ylim([0,13])
plt.xlim([1,24])
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(b=True,which='major',color='k',alpha=0.2,linestyle='dotted')
plt.grid(b=False,which='minor',color='k',alpha=0.2,linestyle='dotted')

bin_centers = 0.5 * diff(bins) + bins[:-1]
for count, x in zip(counts, bin_centers):
    # Label the raw counts
    ax.annotate(str(count), xy=(x, 0), xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'),
        xytext=(0, -18), textcoords='offset points', va='top', ha='center')


def autolabel(rects):
# attach some text labels
    for ii,rect in enumerate(rects):
        height = rect.get_height()
        plt.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.02*height, counts[ii],
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(patches)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The link seems to be broken

Comment: Oh sorry! Is it ok now?

Comment: yes, it is OK. // used to get more than 15 characters. Ignore it

Comment: [Here is your answer!!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352740/matplotlib-label-each-bin)

Comment: This community is fantastic. Thank you to "ThePredator" and "Ffisegydd" for your suggestions. Both were necessary in order to answer this. I'm not sure if you are allowed to answer your own question but ill add the final result as an edit to the code. Thanks so much!