# Type Error for histogram

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to play with Joe Kington's code from this question [Matplotlib - label each bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352740/matplotlib-label-each-bin)

but when I run my code, I receive the error message

```
len() of unsized object
```

for the line

```
counts, bins, patches = ax.hist(data, facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='gray')
```

Does anybody know the potential reason for this?

The data is a few hundred rows and 2 columns of floats.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

data = df[df.columns[1:]]
print(data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
counts, bins, patches = ax.hist(data, facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='gray')

# Set the ticks to be at the edges of the bins.
ax.set_xticks(bins)
# Set the xaxis's tick labels to be formatted with 1 decimal place...
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))

# Change the colors of bars at the edges...
twentyfifth, seventyfifth = np.percentile(data, [25, 75])
for patch, rightside, leftside in zip(patches, bins[1:], bins[:-1]):
    if rightside < twentyfifth:
        patch.set_facecolor('green')
    elif leftside > seventyfifth:
        patch.set_facecolor('red')

# Label the raw counts and the percentages below the x-axis...
bin_centers = 0.5 * np.diff(bins) + bins[:-1]
for count, x in zip(counts, bin_centers):
    # Label the raw counts
    ax.annotate(str(count), xy=(x, 0), xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'),
        xytext=(0, -18), textcoords='offset points', va='top', ha='center')

    # Label the percentages
    percent = '%0.0f%%' % (100 * float(count) / counts.sum())
    ax.annotate(percent, xy=(x, 0), xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'),
        xytext=(0, -32), textcoords='offset points', va='top', ha='center')


# Give ourselves some more room at the bottom of the plot
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.show()
```

the print(data) gives me this:

```
0 1490.68 967.20 
1 1485.69 978.55 
2 1286.84 512.02 
3 1257.85 858.85 
4 1257.17 693.87
```

5 1288.44 591.80
...

Comment: what does the line `print(data)` show?

Comment: @Julien Greenland mass (in Gt)  Antarctica mass (in Gt)
0                1490.68                967.20
1                1485.69                978.55
2                1286.84                512.02
3                1257.85                858.85
4                1257.17                693.87
5                1288.44                591.80
(2 columns, and about a hundred more rows)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure you have read [ask] and [mcve]. When reporting about an undesired behaviour like an error, you need to include a [mcve] of the issue and the full error traceback, not just the last line of it. Try to use some random data inside the code. Also see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: can you please format that print(data) result in the body of the question? Without line breaks its hard to tell what its shaped like. Since the code in the linked example works fine, i presume theres something weird floating around inside "data" or the preceding "df"

Comment: Hey @Dylan , I edited my question and put the print output at the end of my question. Might the negative numbers be a problem that come after the 50th row?